# AWS Cognito force refresh session

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm running into some problems when I attempt to refresh my session tokens, (Access, Id, Refresh). I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442973/cognito-user-pool-how-to-refresh-access-token-using-refresh-token) and the answer has helped me understand what is going on some. But I feel what I am trying to do isn't quite what `getSession` is for.

I am attempting to implement a session expiration message (done) that allows the user to extend their session (refreshes the tokens). From what I gather about `getSession()`, it returns either the old tokens, if they are still valid, or new tokens if they are not valid. Please correct me if I am wrong there.

I am attempting to give the user new/refreshed tokens every time they click on extend session. For dev purposes, I have a button which then displays the message with the extend session button. The tokens I receive when I call `getSession()` are the old ones, but I want them to be new ones.

So basically, nullifying the old session and giving them a new one.

My questions are:

1. Am I missing some understanding about `getSession()`, as previously mentioned?
2. Can I give the user new session tokens (Access, Id, Refresh)?
3. Can I do #2 without having the user sign in again?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:
It may help to know that I am not using any Federated Identities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call cognitoUser.refreshSession. I've found a reasonable example for you over here:

[Sample code: how to refresh session of Cognito User Pools with Node.js and Express](https://gist.github.com/kndt84/5be8e86a15468ed1c8fc3699429003ad)

Look for the method called checkTokenExpiration, it explains perfectly well what you have to do to refresh the session.

Comment: I cant believe I didn't see the `refreshSession` method. I will look into it in the next couple of days. Thank you.

Comment: Finally got around to checking it. This is the right answer.

Comment: @HypnicJerk is it possible in aws-amplify

Comment: In aws-amplify you can do: 
`const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
currentUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
});`