# How to refresh the IdToken using refreshToken Value in AWS Cognito?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is it possible we can force expire before one hour and get new IdToken using the refresh token
OR
How to get new IdToken after auto expire time using refreshToken value in this  [amazon-cognito-identity-js-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node) module?

I am getting

> TypeError: refreshToken.getToken is not a function as error.

I am using this code as follows:

```
cognitoUser.refreshSession(refreshToken, (err, session) => {
                          if (err) {//throw err;
                            console.log('In the err'+err);
                          }
                          else{
                            console.log('session '+session);
                          }
                    });
```

I am passing `refreshToken` correct value in the function. 
In the file CognitoUser.js on function

```
refreshSession(refreshToken, callback)
{
  const authParameters = {};
  authParameters.REFRESH_TOKEN = refreshToken.getToken(); /* Here I am getting error*/
  ...
  ....
}
```

In case if I replace second line of function `refreshSession()` with the

```
authParameters.REFRESH_TOKEN = this.signInUserSession.getRefreshToken().getToken();
```

then error went off.

I have tried to use the code as follows:

```
 var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: 'xx-xxx-x_xxxxx',
        ClientId: 'xxxxx',
        AuthFlow: 'xxxxx'
     };

     userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);


if(minuteDiff >= 60) { // Defult Id Token Expired
    // Get New IdToken using RefreshToken
    var userData = {
        Username : cognitousername,
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser  = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

    var refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'); 

    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
        if (err) {                
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
                /* Session Refresh */
                cognitoUser.refreshSession(refreshToken, (err, session) => {

                    if (err) {//throw err;
                        console.log('In the err'+err);
                    }
                    else{
                        var regsmar_apiKey = session.idToken.jwtToken; // will this provide new IdToken?
                        localStorage.setItem('api_key',regsmar_apiKey);
                    }
                }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Can any one please help me out there how should I update IdToken after expire?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think `refreshSession` expects an instance of the `CognitoRefreshToken` class, not just a plain string. The `getToken` is a method from that class that's missing in your case. You may want to try this:

```
var CognitoRefreshToken = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js').CognitoRefreshToken;
...
var token = new CognitoRefreshToken({ RefreshToken: refreshToken })
cognitoUser.refreshSession(token, (err, session) => { ... });
```

I saw it here: https://gist.github.com/kndt84/5be8e86a15468ed1c8fc3699429003ad

Answer (score 3):

working javascript module

```
var refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
var token = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoRefreshToken({ RefreshToken: refreshToken })
cognitoUser.refreshSession(token, function (err, session) {
    console.log(err, session);
    var idToken = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the answer in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556594/aws-cognito-force-refresh-session), Danny Hoek posted a link to an example with Node.js for the refresh method, it may help you achieve that...

[Sample code: how to refresh session of Cognito User Pools with Node.js and Express](https://gist.github.com/kndt84/5be8e86a15468ed1c8fc3699429003ad)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `refreshToken` is not what you're expecting it to be. For example, if you attempt to call `getToken()` on a `undefined` value, it will produce this error.

Can you please post more of the code?

Comment: So can you please elaborate how can I update IdToken after auto expire i.e. 1 hour? Should I re-login again programmatically? Is there any tut or documentation which can help me there?

Comment: Refreshing tokens, either via the RefreshTokens api or the REFRESH_TOKENS(_AUTH) flow of InitiateAuth, is the way to do this. Per the github examples (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js), try getSession to do this.

Comment: Just updated my question with the code, can you please check?

Comment: To be clear, you're getting the above error even when calling getSession? What behavior are you seeing when calling that?

Comment: After getSession is called, 'session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()' should get you what you need.

Comment: @DeepKakkar if this is still not working, perhaps try amending your code to store the refresh token inside your application separately to the library itself, immediately when the user authenticates. If this works, there may be a problem recalling the token from the library itself.