# How do AWS Cognito Authentication tokens refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am not understanding something about Amazon Cognito.  If JWT tokens are only good for an hour, then they need to refresh, but how should my app do this?  How does this happen?  Do you just request new tokens and it remembers the session you are in?  Also, do you store the JWT tokens in the state?  I'm not understanding this, if anyone can help out I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking for token, if the grant_type is authorization_code the token endpoint returns refresh_token

Sample:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd",
 "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je",
 "id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r",
 "token_type":"Bearer", 
 "expires_in":3600
}
```

Then you can exchange the refresh token at the token endpoint to get another token

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token >
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj

grant_type=refresh_token&
client_id=djc98u3jiedmi283eu928&
refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

[Additional documentation can be found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)

Comment: Thanks @qkhanhpro!   How does it work if a user leaves his computer for an hour and comes back.  I want them to still be logged in.  Do you automatically request a new token when this happens?  How does this work?

Comment: If you use the JS SDK, you will get token refresh automatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442973/cognito-user-pool-how-to-refresh-access-token-using-refresh-token
Else you will need to implement your own mechanism